# Three Phase to single phase

Tags: three-phase

I have 1Kw supply of three phase in my home. I need a single output of all three phase and neutral.

E.g If I connect 1 equipment of 600watt 15 amp single phase, now I want equal load 200watt 5 amp on each phase. how I connect this equipment on three phase.

Comment: Why don't you have a power technician do it for you? I don't think it is reasonable for someone to bring you up to speed in a short answer for a task like this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronics design.

Comment: @JYelton: I wouldn't vote to close because the question is "off topic, not about electronics design". (See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83152/how-do-transposition-towers-in-transmission-lines-work for a popular question not about electronics design!) Rather I would VTC based on the poor quality of the question or possibly "too localised".

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic approaches to this.

You could do it electronically, by building a 3-phase power supply that provides DC power to a single-phase inverter.

The other approach is to use a rotary converter, which is basically a 3-phase motor and a single-phase generator integrated onto a common shaft.

Comment: Unless the OP is quite knowledgeable, he is more likely to die trying than to succeed.

Comment: That's why I didn't get into specifics. Generic question gets generic answer. Both solutions are available commercially, so it isn't necessarily a DIY project.

Comment: its common problem in houses where load is not equal and they paying lots of money..if we sync 2 DG power in 1 output then y not sync 3 phase..